# How to increase mysql max_allowed_packet for client?

Tags: windows-7, mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to increase `max_allowed_packet` variable size for MySQL client which is using remote server. I've Googled it and the answers I could find only discussed changing the variable for server.

My client program is MySQL Workbench for Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [**MySQL Documentation on max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

> Some programs such as mysql and mysqldump enable you to change the client-side value by setting max_allowed_packet on the command line or in an option file.

On the command line, to set it to 512M just run mysql client with this:

```
C:\>mysql -u... -p...

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 31
Server version: 5.5.12-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 16777216 |
+--------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set max_allowed_packet=1024 * 1024 * 512;
ERROR 1621 (HY000): SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=1024 * 1024 * 512;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 16777216 |
+--------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

C:\>mysql -u... -p...
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 32
Server version: 5.5.12-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name      | Value     |
+--------------------+-----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 536870912 |
+--------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You have to set it globally. You cannot set it locally.

You need the [**SUPER privilege**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) to set any global variable.

Comment: when i try this command i got error like ERROR 1621 (HY000): SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value

Comment: @MONTYHS Please read my answer real carefully. I already ran `set max_allowed_packet=1024 * 1024 * 512;`, showed the error message, ran `set global max_allowed_packet=1024 * 1024 * 512;` successfully, and then said `You have to set it globally. You cannot set it locally.` . Therefore, my answer is thorough and complete and has been that way since May 3, 2012.